# Why I'm getting Undefined Variable errors?

Tags: php, arrays

I know that it's not necessary to define variables and arrays before using them in PHP. But I'm facing 'Undefined Variable mat1' and 'Undefined Variable mat2' errors when I run the following code:

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
   for($j=0;$j<3;$j++)
   {
       $ans[$i][$j] = 0;
       for($k=0;$k<3;$k++) 
       {
          $ans[$i][$j] = $ans[$i][$j] + $mat1[$i][$k]*$mat2[$k][$j];
       }
   }
}
var_dump($ans);
```

I tried to define them with following 2 lines:

```
$mat1=array(array());
$mat2=array(array());
```

But errors were changed to 'Undefined offset: ...' errors.
Am I missing something in my code?!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to multiply some matrices together (i.e. dot product.) So where have you defined your two matrices, `$mat1` and `$mat2`? Do you know what your matrices are supposed to look like?

Comment: Also the answers to this question are an absolute disaster - I'm on the opinion that there is not enough information in the question to solve OP's answer correctly and thus **answers should be avoided** unless it explains fully why there is an undefined offset error and how it can be prevented - since that's the only thing that can really be achieved with the given info.

Comment: I don't understand the reason behind downvoting. Is it wrong to ask something that I already don't know?! There is a proverb that says It's not bad if you don't know something, it's bad if you don't ask your questions.

Comment: No, it's not bad to ask something you don't know, however StackOverflow encourages you to research the problem thoroughly before posting a new question. Many could argue that you may have not done this.

Comment: I always googling my problems before posting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I'm getting Undefined Variable errors?

Because you haven't defined anything.

Just use

```
$mat1 = $mat2 = array(
            0 => array(
                    0 => 1, 
                    1 => 1, 
                    2 => 1, 
                    3 => 1, 
                    4 => 1, 
                    5 => 1, 
                ),
            1 => array(
                    0 => 2, 
                    1 => 2, 
                    2 => 2, 
                    3 => 2, 
                    4 => 2, 
                    5 => 2, 
                    ),
            2 => array(
                    0 => 3, 
                    1 => 3, 
                    2 => 3, 
                    3 => 3, 
                    4 => 3, 
                    5 => 3, 
            )
    );
```

And test it

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are different than normal variables so you need to define it and most importantly **before accessing any index of an array it is necessary for the array to have values in it**. Otherwise you will get undefined offset error.

Anotherthing is that, instead of using `$mat1=array(array())` you can simply define `$mat1=array()` this will work for multidimensional arrays also.

So **unless your array actually have values at those indexes (even if empty values), you will get undefined offset error.**

Answer (score 0):

You still have to have data in order to use the arrays. If mat1 is just an empty array then trying to access $mat1[1]  will give you that undefined offset error